# PhantomJS can't find element by ID of ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I developed a UI Test, which I ran an chrome and it worked. 
Than i installed PhantomJs in my Visual Studio and I get an error. I tried using the XPath, and I tried using the ELement Id, both of them were not found by PhantomJs.

```
public void Vendormaintenance()
{
    Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='ctl00_cphPage_RadGridVendors_ctl00_ctl04_gbcEditCommandColumn']")).Click(); //edit Button

    var vendorName = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_cphPage_RadGridVendors_ctl00_ctl05_EditFormControl_txtName")).GetAttribute("Value"); //Lieferanten Name

    Wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("ctl00_cphPage_RadGridVendors_ctl00_ctl05_EditFormControl_lblEditVendorsHeader")));


    var vendorCode = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_cphPage_RadGridVendors_ctl00_ctl05_EditFormControl_txtCode")).GetAttribute("value"); //LieferantenCode

    var textName = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_cphPage_RadGridVendors_ctl00_ctl05_EditFormControl_txtName")); //Lieferanten Name bearbeiten

    textName.Clear();
    textName.SendKeys("Mc Donalds");
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    var safe = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_cphPage_RadGridVendors_ctl00_ctl05_EditFormControl_btnUpdateEditOperands_input"));//Safe            
    safe.Click();

    Wait.Until(
       ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(
           By.Id("ctl00_cphPage_RadGridVendors_ctl00_ctl05_EditFormControl_cbDocumentApproved")));

    var vendorCodeField = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_cphPage_RadGridVendors_ctl00_ctl02_ctl02_FilterTextBox_columnCode")); //Lieferanten Code Eingabefeld
    vendorCodeField.SendKeys(vendorCode);
    vendorCodeField.SendKeys(Keys.Return);


    Wait.Until(
       ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(
          By.Id("ctl00_cphPage_RadGridVendors_ctl00_ctl16_gbcEditCommandColumn"))); //This is where I get this: "An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException' occurred in WebDriver.Support.dll but was not handled in user code"

    var vendorName2 = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='ctl00_cphPage_RadGridVendors_ctl00__0']/td[5]")).Text;

    Assert.AreEqual("Mc Donalds", vendorName2);

    ResetVendorName(vendorName, safe, vendorName2, vendorCode);
}
```

Does anyone have solution to this Problem or knows why it doesn't work?

Comment: what error did you get? Add it to your question please.

Comment: Have you checked in the html code (into the driver variable) if the if really exists?